# Choice of coefficients in simplicial homology: $\mathbb Z$ vs. $\mathbb Z_2$

Tags: reference-request, homology-cohomology

I am just starting in simplicial homology (on the way to TDA, not singular homology or homology theory in general), and I have read several articles and books that either use coefficients in either $\mathbb Z$ or $\mathbb Z_2$. As I mostly self-study these topics I find it hard to understand why the choice of coefficients is relevant. I'd like to ask a few concrete questions and would appreciate it if someone could give some small insight too:

- Is it right to assume that using $\mathbb Z_2$ makes computations easier, since we don't worry about the sign (and thus we lose the information given by an oriented simplicial complex)?
- Do coefficients in $\mathbb Z$ help "count" the number of times a cycle revolves around itself (not sure if this question even makes sense), like the way $\mathcal S^1$ has its first homotopy group be $\mathbb Z$?
- Just what exactly do simplicial homology groups count? Betti numbers count the "number of holes" (which is already clear for me), but what other information could possibly be encoded by the groups themselves?

As a final question, could someone please point out some good and less obvious references for initiating in homology?